# remove UITableViewCell inside it's custom class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made a custom class for my `tableViewCell` and there is a `uibutton` on the cell which removes the cell by tapping on it. How should I delete that row from `UITableView` inside it's custom class ?

This is the button action and custom `tableviewcell` :

```
class shopingCart_cell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var img_product: mainImage_littleRounded!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_title: label_title!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_price_tak: lbl_sh_prce_kol!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_price_kol: lbl_sh_prce_kol!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl_total_num: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn_stepper: UIStepper!
    var crProduct:productMD!

    @IBAction func btn_remove_prod(sender: AnyObject) {
        dataService.instance.removeFromShopingCart(crProduct)
       //remove the cell current cell here
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should not be handled by the cell. Instead, you can create an `IBOutlet` for the `UIButton` and add an action where the `UITableView` is located.

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
cell.btn_remove.tag = indexPath.row
cell.btn_remove.addTarget(self, action: "removeCell:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Then use this function:

```
func removeCell(sender: AnyObject) {
    myTableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(NSIndexPath(forRow:sender.tag, inSection: 0), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
}
```